# Are Flynn's ISOs a miracle?

Tags: tron-legacy

Flynn states that the ISOs in *Tron: Legacy* spontaneously arose within the grid. That strongly suggests that they would *keep* spontaneously occurring (e.g. as long as the grid remains they will always appear).

Is there anything to suggest that they were either

- A miraculous one-off
- Just a normal 'emergent phenomenon'?

Answer (score 1):

The Comic Prequel [Tron : Betrayal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron:_Betrayal) indicates that the ISOs are emerging from the "Sea of Simulation" at a pretty steady rate, slowly at first but in increasing numbers.

Threatened by this (and having been warned, by Flynn of the additional strain they're putting on the Grid's limited resources) Clu hatches an evil plan to prevent them from spreading further, poisoning the Sea of Simulation with a series of virus bombs and beginning a pogrom against the ISOs.

To answer your specific questions:

- **The ISOs were not a one-off. They were emerging at a fairly steady rate**
  and
- **With the sea poisoned, there was little to no chance of further ISOs developing**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rough timeline itself was a good indication that the ISOs were a miraculous one-off phenomenon.  The ISOs sprang into being, Clu eradicated them in the ultimate ragequit, Kevin Flynn went into self-imposed exile and then... nothing.  The ISOs did not re-emerge despite two decades passing on the outside and a few thousand years passing in the Grid universe.

Comment: Ah, but that whole time CLU was actively suppressing any evidence of machine evolution.

Comment: @Richard Shown in _TRON: Uprising_, it took a long time to track down all the ISOs, with indications that it was a one-time event - only the original "batch" were ever mentioned, and it would've been harder to keep getting rid of them

Comment: @izkata - The comic series would suggest that their emergence was at a pretty steady rate rather than a one off

Answer (score -1):

Somewhere... probably in the animated series (Tron: Uprising)... it mentions that after Clu eradicated the ISOs, he somehow "poisoned" the sea of simulation to keep any more of them from appearing.